# Данные с плавающей запятой в DataGrid C# MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, числа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Мне необходимо чтобы в DataGrid в колонку "Задолженность" выводилось число с 2 знаками после запятой. Выводится 4 знака после запятой.  В чем может быть причина?
помогите плиз.
Тип в MySql стоит Decimal (10.2)

```
 string SQL =
            "SELECT gp.name, st.FIO, gp.cost/12 - (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(pais),0) " +
            "FROM kassir WHERE MONTH(date) = '"+month+"' AND YEAR(date) = '"+Yeat+"'AND FIO = st.FIO) as 'dolg' FROM student st " +
            "LEFT JOIN `group` gp ON st.group = gp.name " +
            "LEFT JOIN kassir kass ON st.FIO = kass.FIO " +
            "WHERE st.start < '"+dateTime+"' AND st.stop >'"+dateTime+"' GROUP BY FIO";


        dataReader = conn.DataReader(SQL);
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            if (Convert.ToDecimal(dataReader["dolg"].ToString()) > 0)
            {

                dolgCol.Add(new Dolg_list()
                {

                    FIO = dataReader["FIO"].ToString(),
                    dolg = dataReader["dolg"].ToString() + "рублей",
                    group = dataReader["name"].ToString(), //Колонка задолженность

                }) ;; 
            }

        }
        conn.CloseConnection();
        return dolgCol;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тип в БД может стоять какой вам больше нравится, просто отформатируйте выводимые значения.

```
string strValue = 0.3333333333333D.ToString("F2");
```

> 0.33

Comment: dolg = dataReader["dolg"].ToString()       В этой строке пытаюсь сделать форматирование выдает ошибку (((

Comment: @Andreevich и не должно. У `DataReader` на выходе `object`, сделайте сначала каст к `decimal` или `double`, я не знаю к какому cтипу CLR приводит тип MySQL драйвер ДБ, который вы используете.